# Can we store date in 'YYYYMMDD' format without dashes or slashes for date type date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I tried below code but it stores date with dashes, e.g. `2016-10-12`.

```
Declare @dts table
(
a date
)

insert into @dts (a)
select  format(cast('20161012' as date),'yyyyMMdd')

select * from @dts
```

Comment: No, it *doesn't* store a date with dashes. It stores the number of days that have occurred since January 1st 1 A.D. When you *retrieve it*, something *turns it into a string for display*, and by default, SSMS picks a format that includes dashes. That has *nothing* to do with what was stored, or what you can do with the stored value if *you* control its conversion into a string for display purposes yourself.

Comment: No you can't, a date type is stored with delimiters, if you want to store the date as a number then use the EPOCH date also referred to as UNIX time.  Or if you really want it as YYYYMMDD, then store it as a string varchar(8).

Comment: In general you should store `date` in valid `date` format, and retrieve using your desired format, or you can use `nvarchar` type column, but not recommended

Comment: Please ignore the two comments above this one! And read the first one.

Comment: If you want to change the "default" behaviour how it is displayed on the SQL Server machine it self you would need to change the regional settings of the machine, but keep in mind this will than be a local setting that only applies to the machine it self and the machine as a whole (not just the SQL Server) so ALL dates in every application would than have this dateformat (if they didnt specifiy a specific format for them self).

Comment: You can set the date format in SQL Server with `SET DATEFORMAT` statement. It allows to change date format with limitation that separators will be either from `(/), (-), or (.)`

Comment: The data type of date it s **NOT stored** with dashes at all. The database provides many ways to display dates, you just need to control how it is displayed.  You *could* use an integer or char/varchar to store YYYMMDD data but it is better to use the date type because it gives you access to date arithmetic and logic (e.g. it knows that 20170229 is invalid as a date but it valid as an integer or string).

Answer (score 0):

How about int data type?

```
Declare @dts table
(
a int
)

insert into @dts (a)
select  format(cast('20161012' as date),'yyyyMMdd')

select * from @dts
```

Comment: Storing a `date` as an integer is a really bad idea